# Map Function Doesn't Work as Intended

Tags: haskell, latex

I have a couple of Haskell functions for writing to a .tex file (using the [*HaTeX*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX-3.17.0.2) package) which look like this:

```
theBody :: Monad m => [ Maybe (String, String)] -> LaTeXT_ m
theBody listOfEntries = do
  maketitle
  center $ tabular Nothing [RightColumn, VerticalLine, LeftColumn] $ do
    textbf "Name" & textbf "Tel"
    let removedJusts = map fromJust listOfEntries
    map tableEntry removedJusts

tableEntry :: Monad m => (String, String) -> LaTeXT_ m
tableEntry (name, number) = do
  lnbk
  hline
  do
    textit (fromString name)
    &
    textit (fromString number)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘LaTeXT m ()’ with actual type ‘[LaTeXT_ m0]’
```

Arising from the line where I map the `tableEntry` function to my list of tuples. The list of tuples would look something like this:

```
[("A Name", "12345"), ("Another Name", "54321"), ("Yet Another Name", "98765")]
```

If I replace `map tableEntry removedJusts` with:

```
tableEntry (removedJusts !! 0)
tableEntry (removedJusts !! 1)
tableEntry (removedJusts !! 2)
```

It does indeed add these entries to my tex file, so I can't understand why the map function wouldn't work for the list.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableEntry (removedJusts !! 0)` works because it matches the return type of your `theBody` function (`LaTeXT_ m` or, expanding the type synonym, `LaTeXT m ()`). `map tableEntry removedJusts`, on the other hand, gives a *list* of `LaTeXT_ m`, leading to the type error you have seen. What you actually need here is `mapM_`, which, in addition to mapping, combines all resulting `LaTeXT m ()` computations in a single `LaTeXT m ()`:

```
GHCi> :t mapM_
mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
```

```
theBody :: Monad m => [ Maybe (String, String)] -> LaTeXT_ m
theBody listOfEntries = do
  maketitle
  center $ tabular Nothing [RightColumn, VerticalLine, LeftColumn] $ do
    textbf "Name" & textbf "Tel"
    let removedJusts = map fromJust listOfEntries
    mapM_ tableEntry removedJusts
```

P.S.: A closely related function that you will eventually find useful is `traverse`. Unlike `mapM_`, `traverse` collects, rather than discards, the results of each computation. (Here I used `mapM_` becuase you do want to discard said results, as they are merely `()`.)

P.P.S.: Using `fromJust` is generally not a good idea. It will make your `theBody` crash with a generic error message if there is a `Nothing` in the input list. Better options include `catMaybes` (from `Data.Maybe`), which will silently filter out the `Nothing` values (e.g. `let removedJusts = catMaybes listOfEntries`), and `maybe` and `fromMaybe` (the latter also from `Data.Maybe`), which allow you to choose how to handle `Nothing` values.

Comment: Thanks very much for such a clear and concise explanation - it makes perfect sense now. And thanks for going above and beyond by giving me extra advice about the `fromJust`